# Clean app data is not working

Tags: android, android-tv, data-cleaning

I trying to clean Netflix data, TV version (ninja), from my application. I use the below code:

```
private void clearPreferences() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear com.netflix.ninja");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It compiles but nothing happens.
When I try to do the same through console, it works just fine with:

```
adb shell pm clear com.netflix.ninja
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb shell` runs with higher privileges than does an Android app. Many, if not most, `adb shell` commands simply will not work from an Android app. The exception is if the device is rooted, and you run the command through `su`.

Comment: @RodrigoSalomao: I do not work on apps for rooted devices, and so I do not have the specifics handy.

Comment: Just from the top of my head, I think there is an API for doing this if the app is a device admin (which can be requested without rooting).
For Samsung devices, there is a KNOX API that does this as well.

Comment: It´s a Wetek hub, a device that run Android 6.0 . And yes I have root access but even though it´s is giving me a exception "Permission Danied" on Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su"). What can I do to overcome this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks folks. I got to work using "su" on the command. But I had to root my device first.

Follow the code if someone need it:

```
@OnClick(R.id.clean)
    protected void cleanAppData() {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes("pm clear com.netflix.mediaclient\n");
            dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```